# Creating new DDM type

Tags: liferay

I'm using Liferay 7 and I need to create a custom DDM type, which I'd like to use in structure creation. Can you please guide me how can I achieve that?

What I've read so far, all types are self-contained modules, so I've took `dynamic-data-mapping-type-select` from `modules/apps/forms-and-workflow/dynamic-data-mapping` and created a new project based on them. After deploying a new type is visible in the new form page, but not in structure form. What should I do, to make it visible in case of structures?

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick guess that I'll try to flesh out if I get time today.

I suspect that the Forms App was built *expecting* to need to find any custom ddm-type modules and display them in the UI for selection. The Structures JSP is probably not updated to automatically *expect* to need to to find new types. So, I'm going to guess that there's a JSP that you need to modify somewhere in a `dynamic-data-mapping-*-web` module. Once you find what you need to modify and where it is, you'll be able to do that with a JSP override fragment. see here: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-jsps

Hopefully that at least helps you direct your research into this matter.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to follow that posts: https://web.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/30682458?_ga=1.223113887.505748531.1475581177

Comment: After adding proper entries the type is visible in the new structure form, but I can't use it. In the web console there's an error: `Uncaught TypeError: n.getFieldClass(...) is not a constructor(…)`.